# Making sure an 'int' is bound on sqlite

Tags: iphone

I have a method called like this...

```
-(void)dbUpdate:(int)forId {
```

Which contains this sqlite to bind and update a database.

```
sqlite3_bind_int(UPDATE_ACCOUNT, 3, forId);
```

When I run the query, it doesn't give me an error, but it doesn't update the database either.

If I change this line of code...

```
sqlite3_bind_int(UPDATE_ACCOUNT, 3, forId);
```

manually, to...

```
sqlite3_bind_int(UPDATE_ACCOUNT, 3, 6);
```

the query runs 100% fine, as expected.

Changing the variable to an actual integer proves to me that the variable 'forId' isn't being passed or bound to the query properly.

What am I doing wrong?  How is the best way to pass an Integer (and make sure it is an Integer) into an sqlite bind?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you even debugged what `forId` is at runtime in the function call? There's no difference between passing a literal `6` or an `int` with a value of `6` so `forId` is obviously not `6` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nick, you pointed me in the write direction.

Turns out I was reading the value like this...

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(SELECT_USERNAME, 0)]
```

I needed to bind it back doing this...

```
sqlite3_bind_int(UPDATE_ACCOUNT, 3, [forId intValue]);
```

That fixed it :)